# Cannot find module '../../client/components/layouts/home.jsx' in meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, reactjs

I am learning meteor framework for the first time today. I installed react react-dom and react-mounter through npm instead of atmospherejs.I am facing a problem that says Cannot find module '../../client/components/layouts/home.jsx'. I dont think there is error in path.Because my routing.jsx is inside routing directory that is inside lib directory and home.jsx is inside layouts directory which is inside components subdirectory of client directory.

```
lib - routing - routes.jsx
client - components - layouts - home.jsx
```

[image: projectLayout]

**routes.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'react-mounter';
import HomeLayout from '../../client/components/layouts/home.jsx';
import Layout from '../../client/components/layouts/layout.jsx';

publicRoutes = FlowRouter.group({
    name:'publicroutes'
});

privateRoutes = FlowRouter.group({
    name:'privateroutes'
});

publicRoutes.route('/',{
    name:'Home',
    action(){
        mount(
                HomeLayout, {}
            )
    }
});

publicRoutes.route('/dashboard',{
    name:'Dashboard',
    action(){
        mount(Layout,{
            sidebar:<div>Sidebar</div>,
            content:<div>Content</div>
        })
    }
});
```

**home.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class HomeLayout extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            Features
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
                            Signup
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
    }
}
```

What might be the reason?

Comment: Are you using windows ?

Comment: @PankajJatav nope. I am uisng ubuntu.

Comment: For now you can use the absolute path, I will look into this by tomorrow on my machine. 
Absolute path : import HomeLayout from '/client/components/layouts/home.jsx';

Comment: import Layout from '/client/components/layouts/layout.jsx'; for layout. I hope client folder is on root of app.

Comment: /home/tushant/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.10vjklo++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
      throw(ex);
            ^
Error: Cannot find module '/client/components/layouts/home.jsx'

Comment: @PankajJatav That way i get above error. I have attached my project layout for clarifying the path.

Comment: Ok give me some time I will look into this tonight (IST).

Comment: I know that the client folder is not accessible from server folder. Maybe the same with lib? Try putting everything in imports like the new todos tutorial

Comment: Yes if i shift my routes.jsx files to anywhere inside the client folder then it works.